# PostgreSQL and inheritance

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with this format:

```
Table name : identities

    code   |parent_code|  
    _______|___________|
    AAA    |    Null   | 
    AAB    |    AAA    | 
    AAC    |    Null   | 
    AAD    |    AAC    | 
    AAE    |    AAB    |
```

And I need a way to obtain the highest parent of any "code" in the table.

For instance, if I wanted to get the highest parent of the "code" `AAE` I would get as a result `AAA`, since the parent of `AAE` is `AAB` and the parent of `AAB` is `AAA`, and `AAA` would be the highest because it has no parent assosiated.

My problem is that I can´t modify the tables and I don´t know how to use "with recursive".

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive cte as follows:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select code, parent_code, 1 lvl from identities where code = 'AAE'
    union all
    select i.code, i.parent_code, lvl + 1
    from identities i
    inner join cte c on c.parent_code = i.code 
)
select code 
from cte
where lvl = (select max(lvl) from cte)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ff81accb259917dc2e1da538688f6753)**:

```
| code |
| :--- |
| AAA  |
```